# Are there some accepted names for functions based on the way they return value in C?

Tags: c

I know that in C, we can get values from a function via the return statement or with the use of pointers in the arguments.

simple examples:

```
int myfunction();
void anotherfunction(int*arg);
```

Does C developpers use commonly accepted names to distinguish between (identify) this two kind of functions?

Edit:

I ask this because I have written a ruby C header parser with Clang that I use to generate some ruby bindings(see [truckboris](https://github.com/cedlemo/truckboris)). When I have to transform C functions to ruby functions/methods, I must handle the functions differently if they return value or if they use arguments pointers.

In my code I Would like to use consistent name to identify them and not:

```
FunctionThatReturnValueByReturn
FunctionThatReturnValueByPointer
```

Comment: Does C allow copy elision? In this case ijust wouldn't - as a first order of approximation - use the 2nd one. Aside from that, I'd try to avoid manual name mangling

Comment: @cedlemo I suggest adding the Ruby tag to the question, since this is a problem that other Ruby users may have encountered.

Comment: no, it is all realated to C, I just want to know is there are commonly accepted names for this kind of functions like a function that return void is generaly called a void function. That's all.

Comment: No, because it serves no purpose for a C programmer. The return type and argument types are documented in the function prototype. Therefore, that information is not needed in the function name. The function name describes what the function does.  So if interfacing C to Ruby makes it desirable to encode the function prototype into the function name, that's a Ruby problem, not a C problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just use names to describe what they do.

Also prefixes like `is` `get` `set` are common

Comment: Maroun's comment and Ed's answer pretty much cover it. Only other preference (personal) beyond being consistent and describing what they do, would be to further `classify` the type object you are operating on. (e.g. for string functions `str_settitle`, `str_gettitle`, `str_islower`, etc... ) If you create a stuct representing a point (x,y,z), then `pt_set_x`, ... It just helps keep logic clean and readable as well as providing easy identification when using code documentation utilities like doxygen.

Answer (score -1):

I use return by value for obtaining a new object/variable.

I use the return by pointer for modyfying one or more than one objects/variables.

Whichever you use, the names are meant for understanding. Make sure you are able to understand what the function does with their names.

For a function adding two `int`s,  you can have `int add(int a, int b);`

If you can undertsand, you can also name it `int x(int a, int b)` even though the first approach is preferred.

Comment: What do you mean `first kind` and `second one`? I'm not picking on you, I'm trying to understand what it is you are proposing?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Probably referring to the first and second function prototypes in the question.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the original question was clear enough to understand my answer. Now it has been edited. The person who edited that failed to edit my answer too. Now I edited that one.